# JQ remove objects based on key value

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to delete objects from a JSON payload if they have a key with a specific value

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "DTU1GGfR0eU15hv6KiV_bg6FOJXfUWz4TjIq1H7TGy4",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-28T01:29:46.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "l3EQR6AJ6R1qE1meHyafDnNF8vJ-X-rH1pujxQRTds4",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-28T00:50:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "5fQJY9MprH9b3IstVU1SdfBteUWoF_sdsVuiARPBtTY",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-27T19:01:48.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "0M0fudEmzW9dmAsO3dcWT286tTL6wTX9sllXtsyz-0Q",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-27T18:15:17.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the entire object where `.data[].hash` == `0M0fudEmzW9dmAsO3dcWT286tTL6wTX9sllXtsyz-0Q` to produce:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "DTU1GGfR0eU15hv6KiV_bg6FOJXfUWz4TjIq1H7TGy4",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-28T01:29:46.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "l3EQR6AJ6R1qE1meHyafDnNF8vJ-X-rH1pujxQRTds4",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-28T00:50:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "account": "12xUoMKwf12ABjNx4VCvYcNkX79gW1kzz2JnBLxkFbjswRczRvM",
      "gateway": "113kQU96zqePySTahB7PEde9ZpoWK76DYK1f57wyhjhXCBoAu88",
      "hash": "5fQJY9MprH9b3IstVU1SdfBteUWoF_sdsVuiARPBtTY",
      "timestamp": "2020-08-27T19:01:48.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this possible to do? The size of the object can vary and have many different keys in the payload. The one thing that is constant and unique is the `.data[].hash` key

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **del** along with **select** function such as

```
jq 'del(.data[] | select(.hash == "0M0fudEmzW9dmAsO3dcWT286tTL6wTX9sllXtsyz-0Q"))'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JQOwfm8dsM)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

If the goal really is:

> to delete objects from a JSON payload if they have a key with a specific value

where the key is `hash`,
then you could use `walk` like so:

```
walk(if type=="object" and
          .hash == "0M0fudEmzW9dmAsO3dcWT286tTL6wTX9sllXtsyz-0Q"
     then empty else . end)
```

Notice that there is no reference to `.data` in this program.